# Spacing between the dibros

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment

In both yisro and vaeschanan there is no space between the first and the second commandment but there are spaces between all of the other Commandments. However in the 10th commandment there is a space between the first and the second sentence. Does anyone know why

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/38780/9682

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/79964/9682

Comment: @DanF https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/79964/how-do-we-know-where-the-dibros-start-and-end#comment242871_79964

Comment: Hi Isaac. Welcome to Mi Yodeya. The spacing in the last commandment makes this one commandment, itself, and I think there is universal agreement on that. The discussion is actually the opposite sit. in that the first two commandments have no space. (continued...)

Comment: Think over. Maybe, you want to rephrase your question in terms of the comparison of how the first two were written, i.e. with no space vs. the last single one having two spaces? It is related to the other questions that assume (or not) that having a space is an indication of a separate commandment.

Comment: Maybe you're wrong about how to divide up the 10 commandments and the spacing indicates where the ten commandments are actually. Indeed that is the simplest reading of the verses that אנכי is commandment one, לא תשא is two, etc. and the two לא תחמד are nine and ten respectively

Comment: There simply is no basis for suggesting that the last one gets broken up into two commandments. One person suggested to me that the first two are not separated by his face because there is a tradition that they were both spoken by God.

Comment: Thanks for the welcome words Dan F. I really did have two separate questions both relating to spacing. Btw the first dibros had one peh space whole the second dibros were all samechs. So that was a third question om the same topic