# Difference between the First and Second Commandments

Tags: theology, avodah-zarah, moshe-rabbeinu, pentateuch-chumash, aseres-hadibros

In the Ten Commandments, the First Commandment prohibits having false gods. The Second Commandment prohibits making carved images. Is the problem with carved images that they can be worshiped? If so, does the Second Commandment prohibit anything not already forbidden by the First Commandment?

Comment: I fear you are using a counting of the ten which might confuse some people. https://www.ou.org/judaism-101/glossary/aseret-hadibrot/ might help you out. What you see as 2 separate commandments are actually connected in Jewish thought.

Comment: @rosends https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/38780/how-did-chazal-derive-the-first-two-commandments-if-they-are-both-combined-in-a#comment159223_38780

Answer (score 1):

The first commandment is the existence of Hashem as the unique ruler of the universe and the only power that can be worshipped. The second forbids the belief in multiple deities or the existence of other powers. It also forbids the worship of other powers as a possible deity.

> [Aseret HaDibrot](https://www.ou.org/judaism-101/glossary/aseret-hadibrot/)
>
> 1. “Anochi HaShem Elokecha…” – “I am the L-rd your G-d, etc.” – To have faith in G-d’s existence, His concern for the world, His
>    intervention at will in the affairs of the world, and His infinite
>    might.
> 2. “Lo Yiheheh Lecha …” – “You shall not recognize the gods of others in My presence, etc.” – the prohibition against idolatry. One of the
>    three Cardinal Sins, for which one must give up one’s life rather than
>    violate it.